# Gaussian MRF/Markov Network: the zero precision = no connection?

Tags: machine-learning, graphical-model, bayesian-network

Gaussian MRF in Gaussian information form:

- edge potential: $exp(\frac{-1}{2} y_s\Lambda_{st} y_t)$
- node potential: $exp(\frac{-1}{2} y_t\Lambda_{t} y_t+\eta_ty_t)$

**Why:**

> precision parameter $\Lambda_{st}=0$ <=> $x_s \bot x_t | rests$.

according to books

- Koller's PGM: p.255
- Murphy's MLAPP :eq (19.28).

---

**My reasoning:**
even $\Lambda_st=0$ ,the edge potential of st is > 0,  that means there is connection in between, isn't it?

But they say the connection is absent or $x_s \bot x_t | rests$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\Lambda_{st}=0$ the edge potential would be a constant factor that you could as well absorb into the partition function.